# Unable to stop execution onclick of cancel button

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am processing a page using ajax in struts2.I am not able to stop execution when I click on cancel button of confirm box.

I have added return statement in javascript as well in jsp.

```
var xmlHttp;
        function ajaxEditFunctionCall() {
            var URL = "ProjectName/refreshVoucher.action";
            try {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = showMessage;

            xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

    function showMessage() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                var r = confirm(xmlHttp.responseText);
                if (r) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

JSP file

```
<td><s:submit value="Cancel" cssClass="submitBtn" onclick="return ajaxEditFunctionCall();" /></td>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="refreshVoucher" class="com.action.Action" method="loadAdmin">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/sample.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Comment: confirm() always returns true or false. It is unneeded (and ugly) to use an if-statement here. If you didn't need to change that part of the code as pointed out in the answer below, you should simply do `return confirm( xmlHttp.responseText);` or `return r;` if you want to split it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statement in `showMessage()` is executed long after `ajaxEditFunctionCall()` has completed because the ajax is asyncronous. Suggested solution would be to always return false in the `onclick`. In the ajax call back, check the response and use Javascript to submit the form if required:

```
function ajaxEditFunctionCall() {
    ...
    ...
    return false;
}

function showMessage() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            var r = confirm(xmlHttp.responseText);
            if (r) {
                document.forms["my_form_name"].submit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```